# Нахождение наибольшего общего делителя JAVA (javarush)

Tags: java

Не понимаю, что может быть не так?

Наибольший общий делитель (НОД).
Ввести с клавиатуры 2 целых положительных числа.
Вывести в консоль наибольший общий делитель.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class NOD {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String X = reader.readLine();
        String Y = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        if (X.indexOf("-",0) == -1 || Y.indexOf("-",0) == -1) {
            try {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(X);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(Y);
                System.out.println(MostCommonЬultiple(x, y));
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        } else {}
    }

    public static int MostCommonЬultiple(int x, int y){
        List<Integer> arrayX = del(x);
        List<Integer> arrayY = del(y);
        List<Integer> XandY = CompareArray(arrayX,arrayY);
        return MaxOfCom(XandY);
    }

    public static List<Integer> del(int a){
        List<Integer> divider = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            if (a % i == 0) {
                divider.add(i);
            }
        }
        return divider;
    }

    public static List<Integer> CompareArray(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b){
        List<Integer> compare = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < b.size(); j++){
                if (a.get(i).equals(b.get(j))) compare.add(a.get(i));
            }
        }
        return compare;
    }

    public static int MaxOfCom(List<Integer> a){
        int max = a.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i<a.size();i++){
            if(max<a.get(i)) max = a.get(i);
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: У Javarush ведь есть свой раздел с вопросами, где можно найти ответы на возникающие вопросы по заданиям? Это я к тому, что там вы быстрей найдете ответ, т.к. там у людей голова свежей.

Comment: У вас какой-то сложный алгоритм, попробуйте [Алгоритм Евклида](https://younglinux.info/algorithm/euclidean) (делением), он самый простой и эффективный для нахождения НОД

Comment: Зачем писать свой метод(CompareArray), если у интерфейса list есть прекрасный метод retainAll(Collection<?> c)? Советую хотя бы поверхностно ознакомиться с функционалом сущностей, которые вы часто используете. Для этого нужно набрать в гугле "название_сущности java doc".

Answer (score 2):

Для такой простой задачи это слишком сложный код. Всегда помните про KISS.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class NOD {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                int nod = mostCommonMultiple(Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine()),Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine()));
                System.out.println("NOD: " + nod);            
            } catch (NumberFormatException | UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        private static int mostCommonMultiple(int x, int y) {
            if (x<=0 || y<=0) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Incorrect input");        
            while(x!=0 && y!=0){
                if (x>y) x=x%y;
                else y=y%x;
            }
            return x+y;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tак проще:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int count;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    try {
        x = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        y = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Введи с клавиатуры 2 целых положительных числа.");
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

    count = Math.min(x, y);

    for (int n = count; n >= 1; n--){
        if (x % n == 0 && y % n == 0){
            count = n;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```